# SQL: ignore duplicate columns

Tags: sql

Is there a way to make SQL ignore duplicate columns? (Something like `DISTINCT` but that acts on columns)

For example, this query:

```
SELECT studies.title, studies.* 
FROM studies
```

has a duplicate column `title`.

That is not a problem unless you try to query on that, for example with:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    (SELECT studies.title, studies.* 
     FROM studies) dup
```

Which throws an error:

> Duplicate column name 'title'

I know that modifying the original query to

```
SELECT studies.* 
FROM studies
```

fixes the error, but my query is built in code, and the duplicate *selection* is hard to avoid...

Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using? You're not expected to get that error.

Answer (score 1):

To get around this problem, you may *alias* the first `title` column selected as some other unique name, e.g.

```sql
SELECT s.title AS title1, s.*
FROM studies s;
```

Now the following count query should not throw an error:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM
(
    SELECT s.title AS title1, s.*
    FROM studies s
) t;
```

Comment: Perhaps a syntax error.  (A unqualified `*` in the select list isn't allowed to be combined with anything else.)

Comment: Is there a way to alias a group of columns at the same time? So for example, something that would alias the s.* bit to s_2.*, instead of aliasing the s.title?

Comment: @FranciscoHerrerias-Azcue AFAIK aliases are used one column at a time.